# Merge and make two javascript and jquery as one

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to merge two different code and make them Work together as one the
First one is used to load all the data from sqlite and save edit delete  and the
Second one is used to make them look like a gridview where the label is visible in the front end and the text box is hidden and when the selected row is clicked the label is hidden the text box are visible to edit the selected row and on print button pressed the data is printed on a sapn later that sapan data is used to update sqlite.

But the second js is not working with the first when they are independently run's they work perfect

Example: 1
[Sqlite insert data](http://jsfiddle.net/JpquX/11/#&togetherjs=7t2l5T5uOv) 
 Example: 2
[HTML table View as a Grid](http://jsfiddle.net/vmj5h2a8/9/#&togetherjs=HKlr9ycaAM)

**HTML**

```
 <body onload="loadall();">
        <input type="hidden" id="id" />First name:
        <input type="text" id="firstName" />
        <br/>Last name:
        <input type="text" id="lastName" />
        <br/>Phone:
        <input type="text" id="phone" />
        <br/>
        <button class="reset">Reset Form</button>
        <button class="update">Update</button>
        <button class="insert">Insert</button>
        <button class="drop">Drop Table</button>
        <table id="results" border="1px" cellspacing="1" width="100%" id="results"></table>
        <input id="printdata" type="button" value="printdata" />
        <div class="showresult">1: <span></span>
        </div>
        <div class="showresult">2: <span></span>
        </div>
        <div class="showresult">3: <span></span>
        </div>
        <div class="showresult">4: <span></span>
        </div>
        <div class="showresult">5: <span></span>
        </div>
    </body>
```

**JS**

First:

```
function loadall() {
    var results = $('#results')[0];
    var id = $('#id')[0];
    var firstName = $('#firstName')[0];
    var lastName = $('#lastName')[0];
    var phone = $('#phone')[0];
    var createStatement = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Contacts (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, firstName TEXT, lastName TEXT, phone TEXT)";
    var selectAllStatement = "SELECT * FROM Contacts";
    var insertStatement = "INSERT INTO Contacts (firstName, lastName, phone) VALUES (?, ?, ?)";
    var updateStatement = "UPDATE Contacts SET firstName = ?, lastName = ?, phone = ? WHERE id = ?";
    var deleteStatement = "DELETE FROM Contacts WHERE id=?";
    var dropStatement = "DROP TABLE Contacts";

    var db = openDatabase("AddressBook", "1.0", "Address Book", 200000);
    var dataset;
    createTable();

    function onError(tx, error) {
        alert(error.message);
    }

    function showRecords() {
        results.innerHTML = '';
        db.transaction(function (tx) {
            tx.executeSql(selectAllStatement, [], function (tx, result) {
                dataset = result.rows;
                for (var i = 0, item = null; i < dataset.length; i++) {
                    item = dataset.item(i);
                    $('#results').append('<tr><td><lable>' + item['lastName'] + '</lable><input type="text" value="' + item['lastName'] + '"></input> </td>, <td><lable>' + item['firstName'] + '</lable><input type="text" value="' + item['firstName'] + '"></input></td></tr>');
                }
            });
        });
    }

    function createTable() {
        db.transaction(function (tx) {
            tx.executeSql(createStatement, [], showRecords, onError);
        });
    }

    function insertRecord() {
        db.transaction(function (tx) {
            tx.executeSql(insertStatement, [firstName.value, lastName.value, phone.value], loadAndReset, onError);
        });
    }

    function loadRecord(i) {
        var item = dataset.item(i);
        firstName.value = item['firstName'];
        lastName.value = item['lastName'];
        phone.value = item['phone'];
        id.value = item['id'];
    }

    function updateRecord() {
        db.transaction(function (tx) {
            tx.executeSql(updateStatement, [firstName.value, lastName.value, phone.value, id.value], loadAndReset, onError);
        });
    }

    function deleteRecord(id) {
        db.transaction(function (tx) {
            tx.executeSql(deleteStatement, [id], showRecords, onError);
        });
        resetForm();
    }

    function dropTable() {
        db.transaction(function (tx) {
            tx.executeSql(dropStatement, [], showRecords, onError);
        });
        resetForm();
    }

    function loadAndReset() {
        resetForm();
        showRecords();
    }

    function resetForm() {
        firstName.value = '';
        lastName.value = '';
        phone.value = '';
        id.value = '';
    }

    $('.reset').on('click', resetForm);
    $('.update').on('click', updateRecord);
    $('.insert').on('click', insertRecord);
    $('.drop').on('click', dropTable);

    loadafter();
}
```

Second:

```
function loadafter() 
    $('#results input').hide();
    $('#printdata').fadeTo(0, 0);

    // This shows or hides the button deppending on the inputs
    $('#results tr').on('change keyup click', function () {
        var text = '';
        $('input', this).each(function () {
            text += $(this).val();
        });

        if (text != '') {
            $('#printdata').fadeTo(0, 100);
        } else {
            $('#printdata').fadeTo(0, 0);
        }
    });

    $('#results tr').on('click', function (e) {
        if ($(e.target).is("input") || $(e.target).is("th")) {
            return;

        } else if ($(this).hasClass('selected')) {

            $(this).toggleClass('selected');
            $('input', this).toggle();
            $('label', this).toggle();
        } else {

            $(".my-textbox").focus()
            $('tr.selected input').hide();
            $('tr.selected label').toggle();
            $('tr.selected').toggleClass('selected');
            $(this).toggleClass('selected');
            $('label', this).toggle();
            $('input', this).toggle();
        }
    });

    $('#printdata').click(function () {
        $('.showresult').each(function (index) {
            $('span', this).html('');
            $('span', this).html($('#results .selected input').eq(index).val());
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Why can't you just copy both the contents of the files and place it inside one single file?

Comment: CTRL + C; then CTRL + V. If you're feeling adventurous, replace CTRL+C with CTRL+X

Comment: i did that but the second one does not work with first one am not sure what the problem

Comment: In the second one can't you just put all your event handlers inside doc ready.

Comment: @Jai,Dan White u can check out here i have combined them but still it is not working  http://jsfiddle.net/eK8X5/7010/#&togetherjs=PHtfywKB7C

Answer (score 0):

Well in the second js you have all your event handlers and seems to me you want to bind the events when they appear in the DOM.

So in this case delegation of event is needed. You can delegate to the closest parent which in your case is `#results`:

You can put this function as is in the first js:

```
function loadall() {
    // all the methods 
    // loadafter(); <======you can remove this now.
}

$(function(){
    //hide these with css 
    //$('#results input').hide();
    //$('#printdata').fadeTo(0, 0);

    // This shows or hides the button deppending on the inputs
    $('#results').on('change keyup click', 'tr', function () {
        var text = '';
        $('input', this).each(function () {
            text += $(this).val();
        });

        if (text != '') {
            $('#printdata').fadeTo(0, 100);
        } else {
            $('#printdata').fadeTo(0, 0);
        }
    }).on('click', 'tr', function (e) {
        if ($(e.target).is("input") || $(e.target).is("th")) {
            return;

        } else if ($(this).hasClass('selected')) {

            $(this).toggleClass('selected');
            $('input', this).toggle();
            $('label', this).toggle();
        } else {

            $(".my-textbox").focus()
            $('tr.selected input').hide();
            $('tr.selected label').toggle();
            $('tr.selected').toggleClass('selected');
            $(this).toggleClass('selected');
            $('label', this).toggle();
            $('input', this).toggle();
        }
    }).on('click', '#printdata', function () {
        $('.showresult').each(function (index) {
            $('span', this).html('');
            $('span', this).html($('#results .selected input').eq(index).val());
        });
    });
});
```

---

This one can be written in css for hiding:

```
$('#results input').hide();
$('#printdata').fadeTo(0, 0);

#results input, #printdata{ display:none; }
```

If you want some animation while fadingOut then you might love to use css3 features.